Contrastive Loss from Scratch
I am trying to implement/learn how to implement contrastive loss. Currently my gradients are exploding into infinity and I think I must have misimplemented something. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my loss function and tell if they see an error
class ContrastiveLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, temperature=0.5):
        super(ContrastiveLoss, self).__init__()
        self.temperature = temperature

    def forward(self, projections_1, projections_2):
        z_i = projections_1
        z_j = projections_2
        z_i_norm = F.normalize(z_i, dim=1)
        z_j_norm = F.normalize(z_j, dim=1)
        cosine_num = torch.matmul(z_i, z_j.T)
        cosine_denom = torch.matmul(z_i_norm, z_j_norm.T)
        cosine_similarity = cosine_num / cosine_denom

        numerator = torch.exp(torch.diag(cosine_similarity) / self.temperature)

        denominator = cosine_similarity
        diagonal_indices = torch.arange(denominator.size(0))
        denominator[diagonal_indices, diagonal_indices] = 0
        denominator = torch.exp(torch.sum(cosine_similarity, dim=1))
        loss = -torch.log(numerator / denominator).sum()
        return loss


Your implementation of cosine similarity is wrong. You can see this by inspecting the values of the cosine similarity matrix. Run the following:
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

bs = 8
d_proj = 64
z_i = torch.randn(bs, d_proj)
z_j = torch.randn(bs, d_proj)

z_i_norm = F.normalize(z_i, dim=1)
z_j_norm = F.normalize(z_j, dim=1)

cosine_num = torch.matmul(z_i, z_j.T)
cosine_denom = torch.matmul(z_i_norm, z_j_norm.T)
cosine_similarity = cosine_num / cosine_denom

print(cosine_similarity)

You will see the values in cosine_similarity are quite large (when it should be bounded between -1 and 1).
Below are two correct ways of computing pairwise cosine similarity:
# F.cosine_similarity is preferred for performance
cosine_similarity = F.cosine_similarity(z_i[:,None], z_j[None,:], dim=2)

# alt version to show how cosine similarity is computed 
cosine_similarity = (z_i[:,None] * z_j[None,:]).sum(-1) / (torch.norm(z_i, dim=-1)*torch.norm(z_j, dim=-1))

You also have errors in your cross entropy implementation. For example you shouldn't zero the diagonal values of the denominator, and denominator = torch.exp(torch.sum(cosine_similarity, dim=1)) should instead be denominator = torch.exp(cosine_similarity / temperature).sum(dim=1) (include temperature scaling, sum after exp rather than before).
Overall, you should use F.cross_entropy instead of manually computing the log-exp values - this is much more numerically stable.
cosine_similarity = F.cosine_similarity(z_i[:,None], z_j[None,:], dim=2)
labels = torch.arange(cosine_similarity.shape[0], device=cosine_similarity.device)
loss = F.cross_entropy(cosine_similarity/temperature, labels)


Why shouldnt I zero out the diagonal? I don't quite understand what is wrong with that? It seems mathematically sound no?

Also if you dont mind me asking why add the extra dimension? I can see that it works but that behavior is a bit confusing to me!

We want all pairwise comparisons, so we need the extra dimension for broadcasting. This results in an output of shape (bs, bs) (pairwise comparisons) instead of an output of shape (bs, ) (one to one comparisons on index). Not sure what you mean about the diagonal. Zeroing the diagonal means removing the positive class from the denominator of the cross entropy calculation. I haven't seen it implemented that way. Either way, you should prefer using F.cross_entropy as it implements the log-sum-exp trick which is much more numerically stable

Thanks Karl when I see it like here https://towardsdatascience.com/contrastive-loss-explaned-159f2d4a87ec it looks like they are saying for all i !=k
